# Por qué marca error al querer abrir el modulo o ventana de empleados?

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un panel de control con 4 modulo pero al intentar entrar al modulo de empleados me da error no tengo idea porque ya cheque los object name en el qtdesigner y están iguales, la ventana también se llama igual 'empleados' y ya no se que podría ser.

```
class PanelControl(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(PanelControl, self).__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi('UI/modulos.ui', self)
    self.UiPanel()

def UiPanel(self):
    self.btnEmpleados.clicked.connect(self.fnEmpleados)

def fnEmpleados(self):
    self.hide()
    vModulo = Empleados(self)
    vModulo.show()

class Empleados(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(Empleados, self).__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi('UI/empleados.ui', self)
    self.UiEmpleados()

def UiEmpleados(self):
    self.Carga()
    self.btnBuscar.clicked.connect(self.busquedaE)
    self.btnLimpiar.clicked.connect(self.limpiar)
    self.btnRegistrar.clicked.connect(self.registroE)
    self.btnLimpiar2.clicked.connect(self.limpiar)
```

Tengo ese código pero me marca el siguiente error:

```
  File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\PIA CORRECCION DE BD\PIA_EQ3\PIA_EQ4.py", line 84, in fnEmpleados
    vModulo = Empleados(self)
  File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\PIA CORRECCION DE BD\PIA_EQ3\PIA_EQ4.py", line 203, in _init_
    self.UiEmpleados()
  File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\PIA CORRECCION DE BD\PIA_EQ3\PIA_EQ4.py", line 206, in UiEmpleados
    self.Carga()
  File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\PIA CORRECCION DE BD\PIA_EQ3\PIA_EQ4.py", line 230, in Carga
    self.cmbPuesto.addItem(puesto[1])
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addItem(self, str, userData: Any = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
  addItem(self, QIcon, str, userData: Any = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Comment: Las funciones si están identadas con respecto a las clases solo que no se porque se copio así

Comment: Dónde llamas a `addItem`?

Comment: En un momento lo edito

Comment: Traté quitando el '[0]' pero no me deja

Comment: Pero si el resto del código está como texto, por qué nos castigas con imágenes? :P

Comment: Porque es mucho codigo y me marca error al publicar la pregunta

Comment: Se queja porque hay mucho código y poca diversión. Ehmdigo, poca explicación. Tienes que gastarle más líneas a decir qué debería hacer y qué pasa, etc.

Comment: Te chocaste con un algoritmo que esta diseñado justo para evitar lo que tratas de hacer (pegar mucho código sin dar suficiente explicación). Tenes que convertir tu código en un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)